# Reference referring to multiple objects, how is it possible?

Tags: c++, c++11

In one of the C++ books i am reading :

```
int v[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
for (auto& x : v)
```

When next line in the book says :

*".. a reference cannot be made to refer to a different object after its initialization..."*

x refers to all v's object, how does it work?

Comment: @DanielTrugman That has nothing to do with this

Comment: @PasserBy I realized it a second after tagging. I retagged immediately.

Answer (score 19):

Given a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```
for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
```

It is equivalent to

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    auto __begin = begin_expr ;
    auto __end = end_expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

Here `range_declaration` is your `auto& x`, it is initialized to refer to each element at each iteration, not rebinding the same reference.

Answer (score 14):

> x refers to all v's object

Not at the same time. Each time through the loop `x` is a *new local variable* that refers to a single array element.

In pseudo code¹, it's like

```
for (int* it = std::begin(v); it != std::end(v); ++it)
{
    int& x = *it; // new local variable
    // ...
}
```

---

¹ For specifics, refer here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for